# Add CCK form with overlay or colorbox

Tags: modal-dialogs, forms

I have a CCK form. When users submit the form, and add new content, I would like the form to be viewed in an overlay that allows the form to use all of the browser window's area in a similar manner as colorbox or lightbox.

The reason for this is to provide more screen space for the large form. I have most blocks hidden for this content type, but there is still other page elements and menus ect taking up room.

Also, I am using the multistep module. This means the content is created before submitted. After the first step, the path is no longer /add/[…]. Multistep also provides a block for the form index and progress bar. If I only display the node in colorbox (which is installed and used for other features) then I miss out on the multistep block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I only display the node in colorbox
>   (which is installed and used for other
>   features) then I miss out on the
>   multistep block.

A "quick-and-dirty" solution that I can think of, is to embed the multistep block in the node using the [Insert Block](http://drupal.org/project/insert_block) module. Notice, that if you are using D7, you can check [this](http://drupal.org/node/1021012#comment-4308984), which is a community submitted port of the module.

If this is not what you need, please add a couple of screenshots of the form and the multistep block so that we can understand exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: If I use Insert Block (worried about performance overhead) how do I open in an overlay?

Comment: Basically what you need to do is follow the steps that are described here: http://drupal.org/node/771044#comment-3406332 to add the form in colorbox. Then, somewhere before (or after depending on what you want to do) printing the form, you can add something like this: $block = module_invoke('multistep', 'block', 'view', 1);
print $block['content']; to print the block that you want (without having to install an extra module, i.e. Insert Block)